# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HelpdeskDAL.Employee>' to 'HelpdeskDAL.Employee'

Tags: c#, mongodb, list

Trying to grab all the records from an Employee collection inside a MongoDB database as a method in a DAO, then return them as a list with all instances of Employee. However, when I try to return my empList in this method

```
public Employee GetAll()
{
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();            

    try
    {
        empList.AddRange(repo.GetAll<Employee>().ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeDAO", "GetAll");
    }
    return empList;
}
```

It tells me that I

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'  to
>   'HelpdeskDAL.Employee'" (Error code: CS0029)

which would make sense if only they weren't the same type. I'm failing to see how a List of `HelpdeskDAL.Employee` instances is not the same type as a single `Employee` instance.

Any advice?

Comment: This question is kinda hard to answer because the whole premise is to understand that a single instance and a list of instances are indeed different types.

Comment: "I'm failing to see how a List of HelpdeskDAL.Employee instances is not the same type as a single Employee instance"... what? Maybe you want to read your book again? A List of something is *never* the same as a single something.

Comment: @nvoigt I was confused as to the nature of the error and mis-interpreted it as meaning that it wasn't finding/properly using the Employee type at all in the List, despite it working elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to return the entire list, but your return type is just a single object. Change to a `List<Employee>`:

```
public List<Employee> GetAll() { }
```

You say:

> I'm failing to see how a List of `HelpdeskDAL.Employee` instances is not the same type as a single `Employee` instance.

A `List<T>` is an entirely different object than `T` (in your case `Employee`). You can't swap them out. Think what would happen if you call `emp.Name` on the returning object if it is a list. What `Name`? From which employee? Programming doesn't work with guessing. You need to exactly tell the compiler what you want.

Comment: Haha, such a stupid mistake for me to make. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should return List<> of your Employees:

```
public List<Employee> GetAll()
{
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

    try
    {
        empList.AddRange(repo.GetAll<Employee>().ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeDAO", "GetAll");
    }

    return empList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `empList` is `List<Employee>` type but in your method you are returning `Employee`. Make the method return type `List<Employee>` will solve the problem

```
public List<Employee> GetAll()
{
    List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();            

    try
    {
        empList.AddRange(repo.GetAll<Employee>().ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DALUtils.ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeDAO", "GetAll");
    }
    return empList;
}
```